# Static <div> next to scrolling <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap and I have a div, which inside of that is 2 more side by side. Naturally, I took the row approach to get the desired result, but I ran into a problem. The div I am designing is for a small web widget on ozone (not that that matters now) but when I have the window the size it is going to be it pushes the second div down below.

The code, with them stacked (no `row` implementation) is:

```
<div style="margin: 1em">
    <h4>User Card</h4>
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i>
    <h6>User: {{username.slice(5)}}</h6>
    <h6>Total Score: {{totalscore.toFixed(3)}}%</h6>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </thead>
        <tr data-ng-repeat=" item in infractions | orderBy : '-score' | limitTo : 10 " ng-click="launch()" ng-style="setColor(item.score)">
            <td>{{$index + 1}} </td>
            <td>{{item.name.replace("_"," ")}}</td>
            <td>{{item.score.toFixed(3)}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

So I want the little user icon in the top left corner with username and score below it. And I want the table over to the right (at the same height) but I want to be able to scroll the table if necessary, but the user information to remain static.

**EDIT** Here is the code that has `row` implementation in it but still they only stay in the same row when the window is like 3/4 width.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="margin: 1em">
        <h4>User Card</h4>
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <h6>User: {{username.slice(5)}}</h6>
                    <h6>Total Threat Score: {{totalscore.toFixed(3)}}%</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Risk Model</th>
                            <th>Score</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tr data-ng-repeat=" item in infractions | orderBy : '-score' | limitTo : 10 " ng-click="launchIAT()" ng-style="setColor(item.score)">
                            <td>{{$index + 1}} </td>
                            <td>{{item.name.replace("_"," ")}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.score.toFixed(3)}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `col-sm-*` or `col-xs-*` instead of `col-lg-*`

Comment: good thought, but when I do there is just a TON of wasted space over on the right hand side. There is a threshold for the 2 divs staying on the same line. If i want them on the same line the window has to be 3/4 the width of the screen basically, and the table will be tiny (the `col-sm-3` from above) but the second I shrink the width of the window below that it drops to the next line and the table blows up width wise

Comment: So, you're doing `col-lg-1` and `col-lg-3` for a total of 4 columns in a 12 column layout.  If you want to fill the space I think `col-xs-3` and `col-xs-9` might be what you want.  I'm not sure I fully understand your issue/question though.

Comment: Yeah I am doing 3/9 but its giving me the same result. I Just had that in there from testing stuff out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a roughly working example here:

http://www.bootply.com/xWByEnAkXE

Basically, your 3/4 width issue is with the column tags you're using. You were using col-lg-* which only applies when the browser window is wide, which caused your issue of only staying in the same row when the browser window was large.

The height of the table is tricky unless you set an explicit CSS height on the table with overflow:scroll.

My example uses position:absolute on the table to set the height to 100% of the parent (using top:0;bottom:0). It's not pretty, and it's prone to break if you try to do too much advanced stuff in there, but it gets the job done.

Hope that helps!

Edit: 
Tweaked the example to use media queries.